# How to only pull data from table 1 if table 2 also have data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My problem is, I have two tables that we are using for shipping and this is what is happening. If ca.addr_1 has data is fine but if there is data in c.addr_2 then show it. And what I want is if ca.addr has the data on some line use it but if all lines are null then use c.addr.

```
CO.SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO AS Addr_No,
ISNULL(CA.NAME, C.NAME) AS Name,
ISNULL(CA.ADDR_1, C.ADDR_1) AS Addr_1,
ISNULL(CA.ADDR_2, C.ADDR_2) AS Addr_2,
ISNULL(CA.ADDR_3, C.ADDR_3) AS Addr_3,
ISNULL(CA.CITY, C.CITY) AS City, 
ISNULL(CA.STATE, C.STATE) AS State,
ISNULL(CA.ZIPCODE, C.ZIPCODE) AS ZipCode,
ISNULL(CA.COUNTRY, C.COUNTRY) AS Country,
```

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN should allow you to do what you need.

```
CASE WHEN ca.addr1 IS NULL AND CA.ADDR_2 IS NULL AND CA.ADDR_3 IS NULL
THEN c.addr
ELSE WHEN ....
```

You can add in as many variations using ELSE WHEN as you need to account for whatever permutation of address results you want to select.